# How to make a variable conditional to another variable and assign a value based on probability

Tags: r

I am trying to generate binary variables for A, B, and C. 1 meaning you are a part of said group. Now, with that information, I would like to create another binary variable based on probabilities called X, which assigns 1 and 0 conditional on previous groups. I am trying to figure out what the correct way is for this conditional structure. Listed below are all hypothetical values, this is just a data-generating simulation exercise.

A,B,C binary indicators.

```
A <- c(rep(1,195), rep(0,805))
B <- c(rep(1,90), rep(0,910))
C <-  c(rep(1,715), rep(0,285))
```

Creating X binary indicator, I was pursuing case_when but something is wrong and it is possible I am miss understand the ability of case_when since I have another function embedded in it. So, I understand this is probably not be correct, however, hopefully it illustrates what it is I am aiming to do.

```
mutate(english == case_when(A == 1 ~ rbinom(250,1,.40),
                                B == 1 ~ rbinom(250,1,.90),
                                C == 1 ~ rbinom(500,1,.10))
```

I know I can also use the ifelse function but I am not quite sure how to make that work based on my question -- still trying to think through it. Thank you!

Comment: Hello Sarah, from your example i cant' guess if you're using a data.frame or simple vectors. Can you clarify?

Comment: Hello! Everything is meant to be stored in a data.frame once all variables have been created. So, currently, all variables are currently in vector form. I am trying to figure out how to make 'English' variable conditional on the racial groups (black,hispanic,white) and at that point assign 1 or 0 with probabilities.

Comment: Nevertheless, i suggest you to use `ifelse` in this case. You can use `English <- ifelse(black, rbinom(N, 1, .98), ifelse(hispanic, rbinom(N, 1, .4), ifelse(white, rbinom(N,1, .98), NA)))`. Even you can use `English <- rbinom(N, 1, ifelse(black, .98, ifelse(hispanic,  .4, ifelse(white,  .98, 0))))`.

Comment: where N <- 1000

Comment: In this example, the probabilities of English = 1 are assigned by using publically accessible DOE statistics within the United States. This data is only a simulation and a demonstration and requires a conditional structure.

Comment: The first few rows are simultaneously white, black, and hispanic; whereas the last few rows are neither.  Did you intend for every row to be exactly one race?

Comment: Additionally, it seems that the English variable is running but I am realizing something else. In this example, if someone is Hispanic == 1, then the other two racial variables should be 0. However, this is not the case in my data. Any suggestions on making this conditional on each other as well? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Michael, yes, I think we both identified the same issue here -- as mentioned in my previous comment! Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: In `english == case_when` use only one `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate a list of individuals with a unique race and then randomly assign the english variable, you could use

```
df <- tibble(race = c(rep("black", 195), rep("hispanic", 90), rep("white", 715)),
       english = case_when(race == "black" ~ rbinom(1000, 1, 0.98),
                        race == "hispanic" ~ rbinom(1000, 1, 0.40),
                        race == "white" ~ rbinom(1000, 1, 0.98)))
```

Which does not require binary columns at all.  If you still want them, you could try

```
df <- tibble(row_number = 1:1000,
       temp = 1,
       race = c(rep("black", 195), rep("hispanic", 90), rep("white", 715)),
       english = case_when(race == "black" ~ rbinom(1000, 1, 0.98),
                        race == "hispanic" ~ rbinom(1000, 1, 0.40),
                        race == "white" ~ rbinom(1000, 1, 0.98))) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from =race, values_from = temp, values_fill = 0)
```

If you have another vector

```
other_var <- 1000:1
```

that you want to attach as a column, then you could use either

```
df <- df %>% bind_cols(other = other_var)
```

or

```
df$other <- other_var
```

Comment: `rep()` is vectorized so you just need to call it once - `rep(c("black", "hispanic", "white"), c(195, 90, 715))`.

Comment: Why create `temp` and `temp = 1`? It sould be `values_from = english`. Upvote anyway.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to easily make these variables be stored in data.frame? I have other variables that I need to include that I have already created, but I did not include them in the question, given they seem to be working properly. I need to have all of this information in one d

Comment: @RuiBarradas, I used a constant column 1 to generate the binary variables from the OP's question, not to hold the `english` data.

Comment: @SarahBell you can assign the data frame using `<-`.  I edited the answer to call it `df`.  Then you can add column using `bind_cols` or the `$` operator.  See above